# PostgreSQL ORDER BY column position (and not by column name)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Basically, I don't want:

`SELECT firstname, lastname FROM person ORDER BY lastname;`

But rather:

`SELECT firstname, lastname FROM person ORDER BY <column number 2>;`

I could create a mapping but I was wondering if there is a native trick to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname 
FROM person 
ORDER BY 2;  --2nd column
```

Comment: @jarlh: it's not deprecated in Postgresql (ANSI-SQL maybe): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY

Comment: sorry, I mean ANSI SQL deprecated.

Comment: @jarlh: Can you provide a source where this is deprecated?

Comment: When order by expression was introduced (SQL-99), the sort key changed from <column name> | <unsigned integer> (as in SQL-92), to just <value expression>, and "18) If an <order by clause> is specified, then: a) Let Ki be the <sort key> contained in the i-th <sort specification>. [...] d) Ki shall not be a <literal>."