# ORDER BY and SELECT Same Calculation

Tags: postgresql

I would like to write a SQL command similar to the following to avoid the recalculation of a value. Now, I just duplicate the calculation but it is quite lengthy.

```
SELECT
  *, some_calculation as offset
FROM table
ORDER by offset
```

Please advise.

Comment: ORDER BY some_calculation

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT …) ORDER BY "offset"`. Or if you know how many columns `*` is, you could [order by the last column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27426496/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I already have a nested select because I need a distinct value later. How much will 2 nested selects tank performance?

Comment: @OzanKurt That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @DanGrahn I would hope that the query plan is the same, but you'll have to try

Comment: @DanGrahn: a derived table `select * from (...) as derived_table` has no performance overhead. It's merely syntactic sugar

Comment: @DanGrahn If the calculation is the same, MySQL won’t run it again. It sort of understands and uses it from the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you have written should work, only problem is `offset` is a keyword in `postgresql`. So rename the alias for your calculation.

But if you still want to have `offset` as an alias, add it in double quotes.

```
SELECT
  *, some_calculation as "offset"
FROM table
ORDER by "offset"
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the dumb things.